# Did ngrxLet replacement for smart and dumb components style?

Tags: angular, ngrx

if I build my components with *ngrxLet directive from ngrx, do I need build my components as smart & dumb style?

Answer (score 1):

It's a replacement to the `async as X` pattern.
It doesn't affect the decision to use smart & dumb components.

[Docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="observableNumber$ | async as n">

VS

<ng-container *ngrxLet="observableNumber$ as n">
```

Comment: why I need to do smart and dumb when I handle observables as plain object? the smart-dumb useful to work with plain object instead of observables.

Comment: that's what I say, you don't need smart & dumb if you don't want to.